# How to restore functioning simulator when "react-native run-ios" stops working

Tags: ios, react-native

Yesterday, I was working on my app and all was well.  I had discovered two commands that would reliably start the remote debugger and run the iOS simulator.  These two commands had been working reliably for about 48 hours, and I was so happy that I saved these commands in a text file on my desktop for easy access:

```
open "rndebugger://set-debugger-loc?host=localhost&port=8081"
react-native run-ios
```

Then I made a terrible mistake: I went to sleep. When I woke up, the commands no longer work. The first command launches the debugger, but the second command ("react-native run-ios") produces a variety of results, none helpful (see note below). At best, the simulator launches, but my app is a white screen.

After trying various things (listing processes to see if there is something to kill, rebooting the machine multiple times, etc) I decided to nuke my app and start over. So, I archived my app and created a new app with "create-react-native-app AwesomeProject" etc. I changed into the project directory and then almost ran "npm start" (as the docs suggest) but the terminal output suggested "yarn start" so I went with that. This gave me a QR code for an expo, but I still wanted the simulator on the screen. So I went back to the commands that were so reliable for about 48 hours:

```
open "rndebugger://set-debugger-loc?host=localhost&port=8081"
react-native run-ios
```

But they just don't work anymore.  At best, I can get a simulator on the screen, but if I navigate to my app in the simulator, it is a white screen.  I have tried "Erase all content and settings" in the Hardware menu for the simulator, quit the simulator, etc.

Will I ever be able to view the simulator on my screen again?  Do I need to uninstall expo to get the on-screen simulator back?  Should I just not sleep anymore?  Will I ever reach I point where I can just wake up in the morning, quickly start the simulator and then be an app developer?  Should I just give up on the simulator and adapt my workflow to use a physical device as the simulator?

Edit: To clarify, the variety of results include: simulator not appearing on the screen; simulator appearing and opening to the desktop of the iPhone, but when I navigate to the app and open it, it's a white screen; simulator appearing and app starting without my navigating to it, but it's a white screen.

Edit 2: Here is another data point.  Just now I deleted my app again and created a new one with create-react-native-app.  I then changed into the project directory and ran npm start.  I then get a QR code and have confirmed I can open the app in my device using expo.  And I see this error in my terminal, which might be unrelated to this issue:

```
2:31:11 PM: Error: './assets/icons/icon.png' could not be found, because './assets/icons' is not a subdirectory of any of the roots  ('/Users/me/Apps/MyAwesomeApp')
2:31:11 PM:     at /Users/me/Apps/MyAwesomeApp/node_modules/metro/src/Assets/index.js:192:11
2:31:11 PM:     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
2:31:11 PM:     at step (/Users/me/Apps/MyAwesomeApp/node_modules/metro/src/Assets/index.js:329:347)
2:31:11 PM:     at /Users/me/Apps/MyAwesomeApp/node_modules/metro/src/Assets/index.js:329:507
2:31:11 PM:     at <anonymous>
```

So I have a working app and can test it with my device, but it would be nice to have the simulator on my monitor.  However, "react-native run-ios" is not giving me that.

Comment: "Then I made a terrible mistake: I went to sleep" I hate when I do that.

Comment: Posting the *"variety of results"* might be helpful. Try adding as much info (versions are also useful) as possible in a clear and concise way. Right now, it's really hard to tell what problem you are running into. Please see [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com//help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Michael, I edited my question to clarify what are the variety of results.  I understand the question is a little vague, but that's partly in the interest of brevity, and because I'm not sure additional details are actually helpful in this case... but I'm eager to provide more detail if there is any that would help people help me.  With regard to versions, which ones?  I'm on Mac High Sierra and I think all versions of scripts are very recent, since I'm just getting started with iOS development in the past few weeks and am just following the official docs for react native, primarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the Chrome browser.  Expo expects Chrome to be installed.  With Chrome installed in Mac OS, a remote debugger will open in Chrome any time you run the simulator with `react-native run-ios`.

Answer (score 0):

(Alas, this process below is not working reliably.  It worked once.  Then I tried to integrate opening the debugger into this process.  A short while after posting this StackOverflow answer, I ran 'open "rndebugger://set-debugger-loc?host=localhost&port=8081"'.  This seems to have broken the simulator, though the app still works in my device.  I am now again trying to figure out how to get the simulator working.  For a moment, the following seemed like the correct answer but it's no longer working -- now I get a "Runtime is not ready for debugging" red screen.)

I found a process that in this particular case gets the simulator working again (Update: It doesn't work.  See my note at the top of this answer). I have expo on my Mac and on my devices, so these instructions assume you have the expo app:

- In terminal, create an app with create-react-native-app.  Do not sudo.  No need to be root.  Just a normal user.
- Then, just like the react native docs say, change into the project directory and run 'npm start'.  The terminal output suggests 'yarn start', but 'npm start' works for me.
- When the expo QR code appears in the terminal output, use it.  That is, install your app on a device by using the expo app to read the QR.  Then, I think my next step was to open the expo app and then tap "Go to expo home" and then tap on my app to open it.  And the app started up just fine.
- Then, the real magic happens... I change into the project directory in a separate terminal tab and run "react-native run-ios".  And then the simulator opens on my monitor and my app starts right up.

Thus, it appears that perhaps I had to run the app on my device first before I could open simulator on my Mac.  Running the app on my device seems to get something unstuck.

Comment: It looks like Chrome might be a factor.  I didn't have Chrome installed on this machine.  I saw an error or two in the terminal that mentioned Chrome, so I installed it, and now when I run "react-native run-ios" the simulator opened (and the Chrome debugger page opens as well).  I think the simulator (or something related) might have a dependency on Chrome.